# Wordpress two loops nested

Tags: wordpress, loops, slider

I want to expose an issue concerning the integration of two Loops in Wordpress.
I have this slider (come from WP Coda Slider plugin), which calls pages:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&orderby=title&order=asc'); ?>
<div class="scrollContainer">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="panel" id="<?php echo $post->post_name ; ?>">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

and it works great.
In one page content, I run another php Loop to call the posts list, like this:

```
<?php query_posts ('post_type=post&order=desc'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a rel="group_news" href="<?php the_permalink() ; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ?><?php comments_number('No Comments','1 Comment','% Comments'); ?></li><?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And the list is regularly called in that page, in that slider panel to be more precise.
Unfortunately, posts are also called in next panels of sider, as pages must be, replacing them.
In short:
panel 1: page content (ok)
panel 2: page content (ok)
panel 3: page content - posts list of second loop (ok)
panel 4: post content (wrong)
panel 5: post content (wrong)
...

in panel 4 and 5, I expect to have page 4 and 5 content, not the posts !

I can't solve this
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why not use get_posts in second loop? I think it will solve you problem: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts